# Setting up Arrays in one line

Tags: arrays, game-maker

Im trying to set up an array with six integer values and one string in one line. I know how to do this one line at a time but cant figure out how to set it up in GameMaker.

```
array[0] = 10;
array[1] = 1;
array[2] = 5;
array[3] = 12;
array[4] = 12;
array[5] = 3;
array[6] = spr_sprite;
```

But ideally id like to avoid having multiple lines of code if i can. So how do i set it up in one line?

Comment: I know that C++ supports an inline array definition like this: int foo[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; Not to sure about GML though.

Comment: Maybe you could try the array_create and array_set method, read about it here: http://gmbase.cubedwater.com/index.php?page=arrays

Answer (score 1):

You can use that [extention](https://marketplace.yoyogames.com/assets/2074/number-conversion-and-other) from the Marketplace (script `array_create`). Or create it yourself:

```
/// array_create(value1, value2, ...)
var res;
var n = argument_count - 1;

while (n-- >= 0)
{
    res[n] = argument[n];
}

return res;
```

Old verisons of GMS may use 16 arguments maximum, but some time ago this limit was removed and now you can use about 700 arguments (actually I don't remember exact value and I guess this may differ on different hardware).

On GMS2 you can initialize arrays using [the syntax](http://help.yoyogames.com/hc/en-us/articles/231539867-GameMaker-Studio-2-New-Functions-List)

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```